# How to set combination threshold in Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

There is a description of how to define a custom combination in AutoHotkey:

> You can define a custom combination of two keys (except joystick
> buttons) by using " & " between them. In the below example, you would
> hold down Numpad0 then press the second key to trigger the hotkey:
>
> ```
> Numpad0 & Numpad1::MsgBox "You pressed Numpad1 while holding down Numpad0." 
> Numpad0 & Numpad2::Run "Notepad"
> ```

But I couldn't find how to set the threshold. for example, I want `Numpad0 & Numpad1` only to happen when user presses `Numpad1` in less than 300ms after pressing `Numpad0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this for example:

```
Numpad0::
    if (!PressedAt)
        PressedAt := A_TickCount
return

Numpad0 Up::PressedAt := 0


#If, A_TickCount - PressedAt < 300
Numpad1::MsgBox
#If
```

So use `A_TickCount`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#TickCount)</sup> to compare times.
And the if-statement is there because of Windows' key repeat functionality. Without it, the `PressedAt` time would get set constantly while Numpad0 is held down.
Also, `0` is `false`, so we can conveniently use the `PressedAt` variable in the if-statement as well.

Could've also be done without a context sensitive hotkey for Numpad1, it just makes the key retain its original functionality.
If `#If` were to cause you [trouble](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm#General_Remarks), you can switch over to a normal if-statement check inside the hotkey label.

And be sure to add the `~` prefix<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde)</sup> to the Numpad0 hotkey if you want.